# Open and Done screen is not appearing after programmatically installed APK file in Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-7.0-nougat

I am programatically installing APK and using following code for that :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.QCApp/" +
                            Constants.APP_TYPE + versionName + ".apk"));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setData(apkUri);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                            "/.QCApp/" +
                            Constants.APP_TYPE + versionName + ".apk")),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

But in Android Nougat APK getting successfully installed but "Done" and "Open" screen is not appearing.
What I'm missing ?

Comment: Considering that this flow can be modified by device manufacturers, I would not make any assumptions about the contents of the screens being launched.

Comment: I am testing it on Google Pixel

Comment: But if I manually click on the downloaded APK file from device than this screen is appearing so I think it is not manufacture issue?

Comment: "I am testing it on Google Pixel" -- so? Unless you are only ever going to run your app on that one device, the behavior may be different across devices.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know in case you wanted to know which device I am using